# Selecting single row with no unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so

```
Fld1   Fld2  Fld3
------------
0      1234  ABC
0      1235  DEF
1      1236  GHI
2      1236  JKL
3      1236  MNO
4      1237  PQR
5      1237  STU
6      1237  VWX
```

Note that neither column is unique. There may be many rows with Fld1 = 0, but for all other values Fld1 will be unique and there may be many rows with the same value for Fld2.

I need to select a single row for each value of Fld2 with the highest value in Fld 1.  So the result based on the above data would be

```
Fld1    Fld2   Fl4
------------------
0       1234   ABC
0       1235   DEF
3       1236   MNO 
6       1237   VWX
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative to `GROUP BY` would be to use a windowing function like [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the result.  This function creates a unique number by  partitioning your data by `Fld2` and ordering it by `Fld1 desc`:

```
select Fld1, Fld2, Fld3
from
(
  select Fld1, Fld2, Fld3,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by fld2 order by fld1 desc)
  from yourtable
) d
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea3a5/3).  There are times using `row_number` will be easier when you have additional columns that are unique. This gives a result:

```
| Fld1 | Fld2 | Fld3 |
|------|------|------|
|    0 | 1234 |  ABC |
|    0 | 1235 |  DEF |
|    3 | 1236 |  MNO |
|    6 | 1237 |  VWX |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by`:

```
select max(fld1), fld2
from table t
group by fld2;
```

Comment: Sorry, the question was incomplete, I have now added a third field which complicates the query

Answer (score 0):

a) Get the first result that has only two columns, as per Gordons answer.
b) Use it to query for the remaining columns.

```
SELECT r.* FROM table r
INNER JOIN
(select max(fld1), fld2
from table t
group by fld2) s ON (r.fld1=s.fld1 AND r.fld2=s.fld2)
```